# std::vector, std::move and pointer invalidation

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, stdvector, stdmove

My Question relates to the following pattern...
I would like to use the following pattern to construct a expensive to construct `SomeData`, and then move it to `UsesData`.

So the question is...

Are the pointers in `ud.dat.m_ptrs` guaranteed to still be valid?

```
struct BigObject{};
struct SomeData
{
    SomeData() = default;

    SomeData(const SomeData &) = delete;
    SomeData & operator = (const SomeData &) = delete;

    SomeData(SomeData &&) = default;
    SomeData & operator = (SomeData &&) = default;

    std::vector<BigObject> m_data1; // big vector
    std::vector<BigObject> m_data2; // big vector

    // (m_ptrs.size() == m_data1.size() + m_data2.size())
    // points to elements in m_data1 and m_data2...
    std::vector<const BigObject * const> m_ptrs;
};

struct Builder
{
    Builder() = delete;
    Builder(const Builder &) = delete;
    Builder & operator=(const Builder &) = delete;
    Builder(Builder &&) = delete;
    Builder & operator=(Builder &&) = delete;

    Builder(int a)  
    {
        // makes sure BigObject vectors in SomeDate are constructed correctly
        // builds m_ptrs... vector of ptrs to m_data1 and m_data2
    }

    SomeData dat;
};

struct UsesData
{
    UsesData() = delete;
    UsesData(const UsesData &) = delete;
    UsesData & operator=(const UsesData &) = delete;
    UsesData(UsesData &&) = delete;
    UsesData & operator=(UsesData &&) = delete;

    UsesData(Builder && from) : dat{ std::move(from.dat) }
    {}

    const SomeData dat;
};

int main()
{
    UsesData ud{ Builder{ 1 } };
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pointers will remain valid. According to the behavior of [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) of `std::vector`:

> After container move construction (overload (6)), references,
>   pointers, and iterators (other than the end iterator) to other remain
>   valid, but refer to elements that are now in `*this`. The current
>   standard makes this guarantee via the blanket statement in
>   §23.2.1[container.requirements.general]/12, and a more direct
>   guarantee is under consideration via [LWG 2321](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-active.html#2321).

That means, after being moved, the pointers remain valid and point to the elements which were moved into the new `std::vector`.

Comment: Is it known if the major compilers are fully complaint with this?

Comment: @Quantifeye It's hard to say without confirming with every compiler; according to my experiences gcc/clang would be fine at least.